# How to use enum value as interface key in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am using a GraphQL API and trying to define the typescript types for it.  I now have an enumeration stating all the publication types and i want to define the fields for each of those publication types. For this i am creating an interface where the key is the publication type and the value is the fields that belong to this publication type. To prevent duplicate strings, i want the key of the interface to use the literal PUBLICATION_TYPES enum value. However, Typescript does not checks all types correctly after i try so. The types are as follows:

```
enum PUBLICATION_TYPES {
  ARTICLE_SINGLE = 'Article',
  ARTICLE_LIST = 'Articles',
}

interface ArticleFields {
  title: string;
  body: string
}

interface ArticleResponse {
  [PUBLICATION_TYPES.ARTICLE_SINGLE]: ArticleFields;
}
```

This does compile, however it does not compile to the type i am searching. The output i am looking for is as follows:

```
interface ArticleResponse {
  Article: ArticleFields;
}
```

But this is my current output:

```
let i: ArticleResponse;

i[PUBLICATION_TYPES.ARTICLE_SINGLE].title; 
// This checks and autocompletes correctly.

i[PUBLICATION_TYPES.LIST].foo;
// This also passes all type checks, even though PUBLICATION_TYPES.LIST
// has not been specified as Interface key.
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? I am using Typescript 4.1.3. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Correct me, if I am wrong but seems to be working as expected: https://tsplay.dev/vwjO2N

Comment: it works as expected https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACgqgIQDIEkDCBBAKig8gOQH0sBNGAUQGUoBvAWACgooMAlHNJcwylfAcS5QAvFADkGAE4AXAJYBjADbAxAGkbM2HLoVSUsI8UlkBnaWsYBfRo1khpwSQDMAhvOAsZC5QDFZwRQATE1oNKDlpZQAuKDNJOwBzAG4wgCMAe0CATxi4xKsbBjsHZzcPKTklYFZgEwAHdJATD3omKABteGR0bDwiUgpKADotdB1eAS4AXRiK72A-AOCUhmsGRmksuo9cQwBrYCz0p09K5Rr6xubCxkDgJRdJDwA3R6hZWa8qi4am4BXbJ1EKhMDgCMQyFQRuwxtwJoJyFMhhFlCsAPRoqBYAAWpig8mx9z2IRcIECUBcYGk6Xk6QgdWUDhCtMkT3kkSyQ0KsiB3VBfQhgyGeiwSKc6XSSSgGKgjkk6UkjBlOLxLkUJnSUDqLhMzRJikU4S2HgJRJMqllz1A4Wx6TACWxsGBPTB-UhwxFSsx2J1UBA6WkUFSwGt9Xusic-nJvpQ9kcrncUAOnKAA

Comment: @Nishant You are right, in your example it works exactly as expected. After comparing the tsconfig with mine, i found that i did not have strict mode enabled.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to [Nishant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298455/nishant)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66174674/how-to-use-enum-value-as-interface-key-in-typescript/66205509#comment116993700_66174674) I did not have strict mode enabled.